# Amazon AWS SDK Transfermanager endpoint regions

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, endpoint

I'd like to use the AmazonAWS TransferManager to upload a directory. I successfully create an AmazonS3Client with credentials coming from a TVM.

When I try to download files with it, it complains:

```
final MultipleFileDownload fileDownloadd=mTransferManager.downloadDirectory(ChanAuth.getBucketName(), remotePath, file);
```

**AWS Error Code: PermanentRedirect, AWS Error Message: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint**

I've read about the subject, and experienced it in the past in other programming languages. I remember it has relation on where you do the final "post" when issuing S3 commands (I had to post directly to my bucket url). But the error comes from deep into the AWS SDK and should be handled there.

My buckets are located on the EU-WEST-1 region.

I initialize the client both with

```
s3Client.setRegion(Regions....(Region.EU_WEST_1))
```

and

```
s3Client.setEndpoint("s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
```

but I always get TransferManager complaining.

I suspect it must be a silly issue, but I'm getting stuck in the million lines and methods of the AwS SDK. There has to be somewhere to set the endpoint correctly or the sdk wouldnt work for buckets outside the US-region.

Help Appreciated :)

```
            06-09 20:16:02.810: D/SynchroService(4408): MESSAGE: nicebeat SYNC
            06-09 20:16:02.810: D/SynchroService(4408): MESSAGE: downlading from chd68f38e7d1360dc1d999354da4f98601/nicebeat/story/sonidonia to /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.regaliz.libneo/files/nicebeat/story/sonidonia/lib
            06-09 20:16:02.810: D/SynchroService(4408): is directory? true
            06-09 20:16:03.490: W/System.err(4408): AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 301, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: 2695AE32DC39077E, AWS Error Code: PermanentRedirect, AWS Error Message: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint., S3 Extended Request ID: j9zQ8EBzkCGHkRTveri82HoA/Yh9PvJofUPtNJlc9oKrVutG0VjNEGG90WnTGaN4
            06-09 20:16:03.490: W/System.err(4408):     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:633)
            06-09 20:16:03.490: W/System.err(4408):     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:327)
            06-09 20:16:03.490: W/System.err(4408):     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:179)
            06-09 20:16:03.490: W/System.err(4408):     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2980)
            06-09 20:16:03.490: W/System.err(4408):     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:2951)
            06-09 20:16:03.490: W/System.err(4408):     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:479)
            06-09 20:16:03.490: W/System.err(4408):     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager.downloadDirectory(TransferManager.java:588)
            06-09 20:16:03.490: W/System.err(4408):     at com.regaliz.services.Synchro.downloadDirectory(Synchro.java:156)
            06-09 20:16:03.490: W/System.err(4408):     at com.regaliz.services.Synchro.request_commands(Synchro.java:99)
            06-09 20:16:03.490: W/System.err(4408):     at com.regaliz.services.Synchro$3.run(Synchro.java:195)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set end points matching with where the buckets are created.

For example : if "mybucket" is created under EU, for the s3client you are creating should be set endpoint as "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com".

Similarly, depending on where your bucket was created, you can setendpoints based on this page : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region

Comment: hey! I already solved it, some of my buckets were incorrectly moved to the wrong region. I accept your answer anyway, for the answering effort :)

Answer (score -1):

For users from different regions, with different endpoints can refer this:
**http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region**

If you don't know what exactly your endpoint is you can traverse through all the endpoints and try for each, and zero in on correct endpoint.

```
private String[] endPoints = new String[] { "s3.amazonaws.com",
            "s3-external-1.amazonaws.com", "s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
            "s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com", "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
            "s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com",
            "s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com",
            "s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com", "s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com" };

private int currentIndex = 0;

protected S3TaskResult upload(String filePath) {
        String endPoint = endPoints[currentIndex++];

        S3TaskResult result = new S3TaskResult();

        // Put the image data into S3.
        try {
            // s3Client.createBucket(Constants.getPictureBucket());"

            s3Client.setEndpoint(endPoint);
            // Content type is determined by file extension.
            PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(
                    Constants.getPictureBucket(), Constants.PICTURE_NAME,
                    new java.io.File(filePath));
            por.setProgressListener(this);
            s3Client.putObject(por);

            Log.d("S3","SUCCESSFUL ENDPOINT : "+endPoint); // GOT IT!!

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            if (currentIndex < endPoints.length) {
                upload(filePath);

            } 
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
```